# How would I show the file name of an image when clicking on it using addEventListener?

Tags: javascript, html, addeventlistener

I have a grid of images on an HTML page, and I'm trying to create an alert with the name of the image file when clicking on it. I am pulling images from a python script in an array `urls`

Below is my HTML code, including the relevant JS section. I have tried without passing any variables to the function (using `alert(document.src)`) but clicking the image gives 'Undefined' in an alert. I have also tried passing a variable into the function and calling that in my alert, but that displays '[object MouseEvent]'.

What do I change in my function to display the original image file name, and is there a way to add flexibility to the function so that the same function is run regardless of which image is clicked, rather than repeat the same function for all four images?

```
<tr>
  <div class="row">
    <td> <img src="{{ urls[0] }}" id="img0"></td>
    <td> <img src="{{ urls[1] }}" id="img1"></td>
    <td> <img src="{{ urls[2] }}" id="img2"></td>
    <td> <img src="{{ urls[3] }}" id="img3"></td>
  </div>
</tr>

<script>
      document.getElementById("img0").addEventListener("click", myFunction, false);

      function myFunction(image) {
        alert(image);
        // alert(document.src);
      }
    </script>
```

EDIT: Reproducible example per @hev1's ask

Changes - I have swapped out urls[k] with direct links to images to cut out the step of pulling images from my main.py script. The commented out portion of the JS works great (clicking the first image alerts the url to that image), but the `querySelectorAll` is causing zero response (including in the console log) when clicking any of the images.

```
<tr>
  <div class="row">
    <td> <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/cdn-origin-etr.akc.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/12231413/Labrador-Retriever-MP.jpg" id="img0"></td>
    <td> <img src="https://d17fnq9dkz9hgj.cloudfront.net/uploads/2020/04/shelter-dog-cropped-1-632x329.jpg" id="img1"></td>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <td> <img src="https://hips.hearstapps.com/countryliving.cdnds.net/17/47/1511194376-cavachon-puppy-christmas.jpg" id="img2"></td>
    <td> <img src="https://dogtime.com/assets/uploads/2011/03/puppy-development-1280x720.jpg" id="img3"></td>
  </div>
</tr>

<script>
  // document.getElementById("img0").addEventListener("click", myFunction, false);
  document.querySelectorAll(".row > td > img").forEach(img => img.addEventListener("click", myFunction, false));


  function myFunction() {
    alert(this.src);
  }
</script>
```

Comment: console.log(image) when click please

Comment: In the event handler, use `alert(this.src)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `event.target` which returns the Element, where the event came from.

### Demo:

```js
const images = document.querySelectorAll("img")

images.forEach(function(img){
  img.addEventListener("click", function(event){
  console.log(event.target.src);
  })
})
```

```css
img {
  height: 10em;
}
```

```html
<p>Click an image, to see its source in the console<p>
<img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100">
<img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300">
<img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200">
<img src="http://via.placeholder.com/500">
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `this.src`.

```
function myFunction() {
    alert(this.src);
}
```

To attach the event handler to all the images, you can use `document.querySelectorAll`.

```
document.querySelectorAll("img").forEach(img => img.addEventListener("click", myFunction, false));
```

Comment: The first part worked perfectly! But when I replaced `document.getElementById("img0").addEventListener("click", myFunction, false);` with `document.querySelectorAll(".row > td > img").forEach(img => img.addEventListener("click", myFunction, false));` I no longer get any response when clicking the images, and nothing happens in the console log either

Comment: @Henrik Could you please provide a reproducible example?

Comment: @Henrik The problem was that you had an invalid table structure. Using `document.querySelectorAll("img")` fixes it.

Comment: @Henrik No problem.

Answer (score 1):

you can play around.

```js
const data = [
  {
    id: 'img_1',
    src: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/cdn-origin-etr.akc.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/12231413/Labrador-Retriever-MP.jpg',
    alt: 'This is image!'
  },
  {
    id: 'img_2',
    src: 'https://hips.hearstapps.com/countryliving.cdnds.net/17/47/1511194376-cavachon-puppy-christmas.jpg',
    alt: 'This is image!'
  }
];

const ul = document.createElement('ul');
const appDiv = document.getElementById('app');
ul.style.listStyle = 'none';

const drowList = () => {
  data.map(img => {
    const li = document.createElement('li');
    const liImg = document.createElement('img'); 
    liImg.src =  img.src; 
    liImg.alt = img.alt;
    liImg.title = img.alt;
    liImg.id = img.id;

    liImg.style.width = '200px';
    liImg.style.height = '150px';
    liImg.addEventListener('click', () => alertImage(img.alt))

    li.appendChild(liImg);
    ul.appendChild(li);
  })
}

const alertImage = (img) => {
  alert(img)
}

drowList()
appDiv.appendChild(ul);
```

```html
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you! This seems like another great option to work with